# postMessage from iframe to parent with click event

Tags: events, iframe, click, cross-domain, postmessage

Im trying to receive from the iframe a variable using a click event to send the message to the parent (cross-domain). Want to change the height of the iframe with the receiving message info. Tried many times but nothing worked.

This is the script using in the parent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).bind('message', function(event){
        var height,
        oEvent = event.originalEvent; 
        if (oEvent.origin != 'http://some-domain-name.com') { 
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#autoIframe').css('height' , height + 'px');}
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is what im using on the domain of the iframe:

```
<script>
if (top != self) {
    jQuery(function($) {
        if (!!window.postMessage) {
            $('#bestellen_oben').click(function(){
                parent.postMessage('5000', '*');
            });
        }
    })
} 
</script>
```

Do anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: It work for me on localhost if I set postMessage second parameter to `http://localhost`

Answer (score 4):

Your code is pretty close, the following is needed in order to make it work:

- If you are testing this in Chrome using local files (what I just did), Chrome's local file policy will not allow this. There may be some fix for it, but I'm not aware of what it is.  Simplest is to just use it on a local web server.  See this question for more info: [Using iframe with local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950598/using-iframe-with-local-files-in-chrome)
- You are missing the assignment of the "height" variable - you pass the data in the post message but don't read it.
- To make your origin verification simpler, compare the post message origin to window.location.origin.

The working version of the parent code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).bind('message', function(event){
        var height,
        oEvent = event.originalEvent; 
        if (oEvent.origin != window.location.origin) {        // compare against window.location.origin
            return false;
        } else {
            height = parseInt(oEvent.data);                   // make sure to assign height
            $('#autoIframe').css('height' , height + 'px');}
    });
});
</script>
```

(The iframe code worked as-is when I tested, no changes needed there.)