# calling one function in an .html into another .html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hi i want to call a function from 1 .html file to another .html file

**Parent.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function alertFunction() 
{
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
<iframe src="childFile.html" width="80%" height="80%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Child.html**

```
<button type="button" onClick="alertFunction()">button</button>
```

So when i hit the parent .html page a frame will open with the button in that frame......and when i click that button it should call that functiona and show the alert in parent.html file

Comment: You should write separate javascript file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onClick="parent.alertFunction()"

window.parent can do the job.

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

for chrome i am getting this but other browser its working....how to resolve it

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know much about Chrome. However, I searched it with google, it seems lots of programmers had encountered the same problem and they already found solutions. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950598/using-iframe-with-local-files-in-chrome

Comment: @taj — Do your development with a local HTTP server instead of pointing the browser directly at your hard drive.