# Why can't I obtain the external nodes in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this piece of code. I can see the iframe content but it seems that edp0 is always undefined. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
   <iframe src="DOM-copyB.html"></iframe>
   <script>
      ed = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument;
      edp0 = ed.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
      edp1 = ed.getElementsByTagName('p')[1];
      alert(edp0);
   </script>
</body></html>
```

Here is DOM-copyB.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head>
<body>
   <p>A<b>B</b>C</p>
   <p>1<b>2</b>3</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: How are these files being served?

Comment: I am just running them in my computer using Chrome. They are not in a server. Does that matter?

Comment: If you reference the file like so, DOM-copyB.html should be in the same directory. Does the content inside DOM-copyB.html appear in your IFrame?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory. I can see that the content is there inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript is probably running before the iframe's content is loaded. Try running your code in window.onload and see if that helps:

```
window.onload = function() {
    ed = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument;
    edp0 = ed.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    edp1 = ed.getElementsByTagName('p')[1];
    alert(edp0);
};
```

If you're not running the code from a server, though, I suspect after you get the code to successfully reference the iframe content, you'll get an error like this in the Chrome console due to Cross-Origin security:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

If you run them from a server, that error should go away. See this question for more details on that:
[Using iframe with local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950598/using-iframe-with-local-files-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about javascript. But jusing jQuery would be much easier:

```
<iframe src="DOM-copyB.html" id="myFrame"></iframe>

<script>
$("#myFrame").contents().find("p");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, I am not using jQuery. Isn't there a Javascript fix?