# Highlight text within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to highlight text which is inside of an iframe.

Outside of an iframe, it works perfectly:

```
$('p').highlight('text');
```

To highlight text within an iframe, I used the following code but it doesn't work:

```
$( 'iframe' ).contents().find('html').highlight('domain');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1tvsj8ho/

On jsfiddle you may get an error (Blocked a frame with origin) but to me that's not important, since I am using a local file.

Comment: is the iframe url on the same domain? If not you cannot do anything to it without the iframe src allowing it.

Comment: maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes, it's a local file on the same domain.

Comment: A local file is considered a different domain if I am not mistaken. You should run the two files on a web server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using iframe with local files in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950598/using-iframe-with-local-files-in-chrome)

Comment: He did say "on the same domain"; it seems fair to assume that that's what he meant by "local".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are on the same domain at a real (non-`file://`) URL, so you have no CORS restrictions to worry about, you should be able to do this by waiting for the iframe's load event to fire before calling your highlight function:

```
$(function() { // document ready for parent window
  // highlight in the parent:
  $('p').highlight('text');

  // highlight inside iframe...
  $('iframe').on('load', function() { // ...when it's ready
    $(this).contents().find('p').highlight('text')
  });
});
```

(It's unfortunately difficult to demonstrate this in a snippet, due to those very same CORS restrictions, but I've tested this on my own localhost and it does work provided the `highlight()` function is defined in the parent window.)