# JS controls on loaded html document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just learning javascript, so I really don't know what I'm doing very much.  At work, we have several intranet websites that we go to to look up information.  I am trying to write something that can expedite this process.  I'm stuck on the very first site, just trying to get it to log in.  I loaded the website in Chrome, and using JQuery commands, I was able to put the username and password in and click the login button programatically.  I am using the following code to load the page...

```
let Hash = 'abc';
let Pass = '123'
let ATSweb = 'https://website.aspx'
let wHeight = window.outerHeight;

function load_home() {
   document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" height =' + wHeight + ' width = "100%" id="ATS" data=' + ATSweb + '></object>';
   $('input#_ctl0__ctl0_FullPageBody_MainColumn_UsernameTextbox').value = Hash;
}

load_home();
```

That JQuery command worked in the original page in the developer console in Chrome, but when it's loaded with this code, it doesn't work.  In the developer console, if I drill down to the page the code is loading, and then I execute the command, it will put the Hash variable into the control.

I am guessing that there is some way of referencing the document that is being imported that I am not aware of.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <main id="main" height = '100%' width = '100%'>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the Console tab of the developer's tools?

Comment: No.  It loads fine with no errors.

Comment: So: _That JQuery command worked in the original page in the developer console in Chrome_ is referring to **what** jQuery (_command_) statement?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I loaded the original page in chrome.  Then in the developer console, I entered this...$('input#_ctl0__ctl0_FullPageBody_MainColumn_UsernameTextbox').value = 'abc'.  And it worked.  But, if I use the code above and get back into the developer pane, that line of code doesn't work.  But, If I get into the elements portion of the developer pane, and drill down to where the imported page is, the line of code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the input value must occur after the external resource (web page in the this case) is loaded.

So when you execute the `$(...)` statement in the Chrome console all of that loading has happened. But, when you place the code above into the web page the order of things changes a bit. That line of code executes and does nothing because the document has not loaded.

It appears that is what is happening based upon your question. So...

**Change**

```
$('input#_ctl0__ctl0_FullPageBody_MainColumn_UsernameTextbox').value = Hash;
```

**To**

```
$('#ATS').on('load', function(){
   $('input#_ctl0__ctl0_FullPageBody_MainColumn_UsernameTextbox').value = Hash;
}
```

If that doesn't work let me know and we can figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I understand what you mean about the page needing to be loaded.  But, the page is totally loaded when I enter the code in the console.  And it only works after I start navigating through the 'Elements' tab and get to the form where the textboxes are.  So, I feel like it has to do with how I am referring to the controls.  But, i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I am beginning to think that this is not at all possible.  I keep running into the following error.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

The problem seems to be accessing the '#document' element below.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js">/script>
    <main id="main>
      <object type="text/html" height="1160" width="100%" id="ATS" data="http://thewebsite.aspx"></object>
      #document
      </object>
    </main>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I got into the console and ran the following lines of code.

```
let frame = document.getElementById('ATS').contentWindow
let pEl = frame.$('#_ctl0__ctl0_FullPageBody_MainColumn_UsernameTextbox')
```

And that second line of code is what produced the error about 'Blocked Frame'.

I came across this [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950598/using-iframe-with-local-files-in-chrome) which talks about blocked frames and using local files, which is what I am doing.

So, unless anyone has any ideas, I'm going to chalk this one up as impossible.

Thanks for taking the time to check this post out and trying to help though.